# cdktf diff command with variables pass

Tags: typescript, cdktf

Can you suggest how can i use cdktf diff to pass multiple var in cli?
terraform plan -var "resourceName=testrg" -var "resourcelocation=eastus"
Similar like above needed in cdktf.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you creating those variables using `TerraformVariable`?

Comment: Yes based on terraform variable

Answer (score 0):

You can set them by [environment variables](https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/environment-variables#tf_var_name). In this example you could do `TF_VAR_resourceName=testrg TF_VAR_resourcelocatio=eastus cdktf plan`.

Comment: Not working  for me

Comment: @AmoghavarshP Could you maybe share a small example that shows how it's not working? That would help me a lot to identify what's going on. One thing I could see is that the variable names are not what you think they are, to double check you'd need to take a look into the cdkt.tf.json file and see which names are used for your variables. (Without the `EXCLUDE_STACK_ID_FROM_LOGICAL_IDS` feature flag set there could be a suffix added to the variable)